# Roles not allowing login page to be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I am attempting to use roles with asp.net identity core, I am using .net core 3.1 I am configurating the services based on this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-role-authorization-to-a-asp-net-mvc-core-application. I am using ApplicaitonUser to extend my fields in the AspnetUser table so that is why i have.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

Instead of

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
```

So here is my configure services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddDbContext<MISDBContext>
      (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MISDBContext>().AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();  //<---- add this line 


        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        //services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(); 
        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("readpolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager", "User"));
            options.AddPolicy("writepolicy",
                builder => builder.RequireRole("Admin", "Manager","Agent"));
        });
    }
```

However when I place this line in

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MISDBContext>().AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

Instead of what I had before.

services.AddDefaultIdentity()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores().AddClaimsPrincipalFactory();

I can no longer access my login page just comes back not found. Not access denied just not found.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being that when you use

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
```

You need to also add which builds up the default routes so it can find your login screens.

```
.AddDefaultUI()
```